# Mysql - which datatype is best for values from 0 to 30.25 with no more than 2 decimal places of precision?

Tags: mysql

I setup a database/website recently where the members have points scored against them.

There are 3 points fields (corresponding to different activities). And the Sum of those 3 fields = their total points.

Initially, I understood they'd always be whole numbers not totally more than 30. So I set the point fields to **INT**

Now they need to be able to have quarter (.25) and half points (.5) assigned.

Am I best to change these points fields to **FLOAT(2,2)**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `DECIMAL(4,2)`. `4` is the **precision** (the total number of digits); `2` is the **scale** (the number of digits to the right of the decimal point).

From [the MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html#id800377):

> #### Fixed-Point (Exact-Value) Types
>
> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data. In MySQL, NUMERIC is implemented as DECIMAL, so the following remarks about DECIMAL apply equally to NUMERIC.

---

Alternately, you could just store an `int` that represents 4 times the "actual" score.
Example: `4.25` would be represented in the database as `17`.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you are doing it may be easier to store the points as .25->1, .5->2, 1->4 (as in number of quaters) that way you can use an int still and just format the output when it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer: Yes.

Yes if you want to have decimal points you can either yes `FLOAT(M,D)` ,  `REAL(M,D)` or `DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D)` however there is some [know issues](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html) involved with MySQL Float which is more or less depending on the Platform.

There is automated rounding with `FLOAT` field which could be a bad or good thing depending on what you want for example `if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.`

Answer (score 0):

you can use DECIMAL(M,D)(fixed point representation) for accuracy otherwise Float is also a good choice.